# Operadores en SQL =* *= como debe quedar esta vista

Tags: sql, sql-server, vistas, operador

Quiero realizar un cambio del codigo de una vista ya que me marca que no es compatible con estos operdores =* *= en sql server 2014 alguin sabe como debe quedar?

En sql server 2014

```
    CREATE view [dbo].[Familiar] as
select 
fam_familiar,
fam_materno,
fam_paterno,
fam_enferme,
fam_escolaridad,
fam_especialidad,
Par_ECEdoCivFam.PAR_DESCRIP1 as fam_idedocivil,
fam_fecnac,
fam_lugarnac,
Par_PSNacFam.PAR_DESCRIP1 as fam_idnacionalidad,
fam_nombre,
fam_ocupacion,
fam_parentesco,
Par_SXSexoFam.PAR_DESCRIP1 as fam_idsexo,
fam_telemensa,
fam_vive
from dhu_familiar,
pnc_parametr Par_ECEdoCivFam,pnc_parametr Par_PSNacFam,pnc_parametr Par_SXSexoFam
where
Par_ECEdoCivFam.PAR_TIPOPARA ='EC' and
Par_ECEdoCivFam.PAR_IDENPARA =* fam_idedocivil and
Par_PSNacFam.PAR_TIPOPARA ='PS' and
Par_PSNacFam.PAR_IDENPARA =* fam_idnacionalidad and
Par_SXSexoFam.PAR_TIPOPARA ='SX' and
Par_SXSexoFam.PAR_IDENPARA =* fam_idsexo
```

Answer (score 2):

Esta es una de las razones por las que repito una y otra vez que este tipo de unir tablas debe ser removido (a menos de que se busque hace un producto cartesiano). Esa sintaxis fue removida de SQL Server para mantener el estándar ANSI SQL-92. Tu consulta quedaría de la situiente forma.

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[Familiar] 
AS
SELECT 
    fam_familiar,
    fam_materno,
    fam_paterno,
    fam_enferme,
    fam_escolaridad,
    fam_especialidad,
    Par_EC.PAR_DESCRIP1 AS fam_idedocivil,
    fam_fecnac,
    fam_lugarnac,
    Par_PS.PAR_DESCRIP1 AS fam_idnacionalidad,
    fam_nombre,
    fam_ocupacion,
    fam_parentesco,
    Par_SX.PAR_DESCRIP1 AS fam_idsexo,
    fam_telemensa,
    fam_vive
FROM dhu_familiar
LEFT JOIN pnc_parametr Par_EC ON Par_EC.PAR_IDENPARA = fam_idedocivil     AND Par_EC.PAR_TIPOPARA ='EC' 
LEFT JOIN pnc_parametr Par_PS ON Par_PS.PAR_IDENPARA = fam_idnacionalidad AND Par_PS.PAR_TIPOPARA ='PS'
LEFT JOIN pnc_parametr Par_SX ON Par_SX.PAR_IDENPARA = fam_idsexo         AND Par_SX.PAR_TIPOPARA ='SX';
```

Comment: aca tienes más información https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/install/outer-join-operators-and-are-not-supported-in-90-or-later-compatibility-modes?view=sql-server-2014

Comment: aunque en este caso parecen ser right join

Comment: @DavidSantos pareciera, pero el asterisco está del lado de la columna que pertenece a dhu_familiar. Analizando la lógica, también tiene sentido que sean LEFT JOIN.

Comment: Si pero si lees el articulo que adjunte explica que "* = operator and an equivalent query that uses the LEFT OUTER JOIN", lo que me lleva a concluir que el =* hace un right join

Comment: y si es un right join https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13382038/operator-in-sql